# Как менять активные элементы?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как добавлять активный класс к элементам по клику на кнопки `nav-prev` и `nav-next`? Проблема с моим скриптом такова: Если активный первый элемент и нажать на кнопку `nav-prev`,то класс пропадет и также с последним элементом, если он активный и нажать на `nav-next`,то активный класс пропадет. 
Как можно это исправить?

```js
$(".nav-prev").click(function() {
  $(".elem.active").removeClass("active").prev().addClass("active");
});

$(".nav-next").click(function() {
  $(".elem.active").removeClass("active").next().addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.elem {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.elem.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="elem">1</div>
  <div class="elem">2</div>
  <div class="elem active">3</div>
  <div class="elem">4</div>
  <div class="elem">5</div>
</div>
<button class="nav-prev">prev</button>
<button class="nav-next">next</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно ограничить переключение для первого и последнего слайдов, предварительно определив кол-во слайдов:

```js
var slides = $('.wrapper .elem').length; // количество слайдов

$(".nav-prev").click(function() {
  var active = $(".elem.active");
  if (active.index() !== 0) { // если слайд не первый
    active.removeClass("active").prev().addClass("active");
  }
});

$(".nav-next").click(function() {
  var active = $(".elem.active");
  if (active.index() !== slides - 1) { // если слайд не последний
    active.removeClass("active").next().addClass("active");
  }
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.elem {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.elem.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="elem">1</div>
  <div class="elem">2</div>
  <div class="elem active">3</div>
  <div class="elem">4</div>
  <div class="elem">5</div>
</div>
<button class="nav-prev">prev</button>
<button class="nav-next">next</button>
```